# Dynamically Allocate a float ** with 1 or 2 dimensions

Tags: c

How does one dynamically allocate either a single dimensional array or a two dimensional array, depending on either the value 1 or 2?

This array needs to hold a `frameCount` number of floats but split between 1 or 2 channels. The first dimension being the channel count and the second being the number of frames. If there are 2 channels, the `frameCount` is split between the 2 dimensions, such as [channelNumber] [frameNumber]

I have the following code but I don't think it is working.

```
float ** arrayToFill = (float **)malloc((frameCount*channelCount)*sizeof(float));
```

My array looks like this in the debugger

[image]

I need to pass a float ** to a function so it can fill the array with as follows

```
- (OSStatus) readFloatsConsecutive:(SInt64)numFrames intoArray:(float**)audio withOffset:(long)offset
{
OSStatus err = noErr;

if (!mExtAFRef) return -1;

int kSegmentSize = (int)(numFrames * mExtAFNumChannels * mExtAFRateRatio + .5);
if (mExtAFRateRatio < 1.) kSegmentSize = (int)(numFrames * mExtAFNumChannels / mExtAFRateRatio + .5);

AudioBufferList bufList;
UInt32 numPackets = numFrames; // Frames to read
UInt32 samples = numPackets * mExtAFNumChannels;
UInt32 loadedPackets = numPackets;


short *data = (short*)malloc(kSegmentSize*sizeof(short));
if (!data) {
    NSLog(@"data is nil");
    goto error;
}


bufList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = mExtAFNumChannels;
bufList.mBuffers[0].mData = data; // data is a pointer (short*) to our sample buffer
bufList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = samples * sizeof(short);

@synchronized(self) {
    err = ExtAudioFileRead(mExtAFRef, &loadedPackets, &bufList);
}
if (err) goto error;

if (audio) {
    for (long c = 0; c < mExtAFNumChannels; c++) {
        if (!audio[c]) continue;
        for (long v = 0; v < numFrames; v++) {
            if (v < loadedPackets) audio[c][v+offset] = (float)data[v*mExtAFNumChannels+c] / 32768.f;
            else audio[c][v+offset] = 0.f;
        }
    }
}

error:
free(data);
if (err != noErr) return err;
if (loadedPackets < numFrames) mExtAFReachedEOF = YES;
mRpos += loadedPackets;
return loadedPackets;
 }
```

Comment: What do you call a two dimensional array? It is usually just a vector of `R*C` elements, and you access explicitly `t[i*R+j]`. Sometimes (e.g. when rows have varying length) you prefer to have an array of array pointers, so accessing `t[i][j]`

Comment: I have been trying to access as array [channelNumber][frameNumber] but the array doesnt get filled with data, I think it is incorrectly malloced.

Comment: No, using `array [channelNumber][frameNumber]` makes sense when you have an array of pointers to arrays. It is not a question of allocation, but of element access.

Comment: Edited question. The function seems to fill the array I pass in with audio[c][v+offset]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your malloc statement is correct, but your type is wrong. Malloc returns an address, (ie a pointer) and the thing at that address is the first of a series of floats. That is, it returns a pointer to a float.

try

```
float * arrayToFill = malloc ( (frameCount * channelCount) * sizeof( float ));
```

If you really need a pointer pointer, then you probably need to malloc something like this:

```
float ** arrayToFill = malloc(frameCount * sizeof(float *));
for(i=0;i<frameCount;i++)
  arrayToFill[i] = malloc(channelCount * sizeof(float));
```

But this is just a guess. The function you are calling **should** be clear on what to pass it.

Comment: How would I pass this to a function requiring a float ** to fill it, and once done, I am unsure how to log these values.

Comment: If you want a `float**` then it is not a two dimensional array, but an array of **pointers** to arrays, so you have to also allocate individually each pointer element of the array of pointers.

Comment: That would tend to indicate that the function wants the array to be a different structure than a simple square grid of floats. Most likely its expecting an array of channel pointers, each pointing to a separate array of floats. You would need to malloc an array of float pointers, one per channel, and then for each channel set its entry to the result of mallocing the frames for that channel.

Comment: Yes, looks like its a 2 dimensional array in this case as I have 2 channels, the first dimension(array) holds an array for each channel. Would I just do something like this then arrayOfSamples[channelNumber] = malloc (frameCount/channelCount) * sizeof(float); for each channel, arrayOfSamples[0] and arrayOfSamples[1] ?

Comment: Thanks, I had a look and that mallocs the other way around, I will just switch the frameCount around with channelCount in the calls and I think that will do. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, ONE of the two arrangements is likely what it is expecting. For all I know, your way was the right one...

Comment: The statement if (v < loadedPackets) audio[c][v+offset] = (float)data[v*mExtAFNumChannels+c] / 32768.f; fills the arrays with channel (c) in first array. I just saw that numberOfFrames id for each channel, obviously as audio in multiple channels contain the same amount of frames. Thanks for the help.